# Удалить часть строки начиная с последнего вхождения определенного символа?

Tags: c#, .net, строки

Нужно удалить часть строки после последнего символа "-" и сам символ
То есть, у меня есть строка `111-222-333-dfgdfgergergertg` и нужно, чтобы в стало:

```
111-222-333
```

Я делаю примерно так, но работает не правильно

```
str.Remove(str.LastIndexOf("-") + 1, str.Length - 1 - str.IndexOf("-"))
```

как это лучше всего реализовать?

Comment: Поздравляю с первым полученным и принятым ответом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Remove_System_Int32_

```
str = str.Remove(str.LastIndexOf("-"));
```